# Convert a date to UNIX timestamp on OpenBSD

Tags: date, openbsd

On OpenBSD 6.3 I can see:

```
foo# date
Sun Apr  1 17:00:45 CEST 2018
foo#
foo# date -d "Sun Apr  1 17:00:45 CEST 2018" +%s
1522594858
foo# date
Sun Apr  1 17:00:59 CEST 2018
foo#
```

that "date" doesn't supports the usual conversion.

The https://www.epochconverter.com/ says that the 1522594858 is:

```
Your time zone: Sunday, April 1, 2018 5:00:58 PM GMT+02:00 DST
```

So the date command I issued only returned the unix timestamp of the CURRENT time, not the time that I have given to convert: "Sun Apr  1 17:00:45 CEST 2018".

**The Question**: how to convert a given date to unix timestamp on OpenBSD? If not with the "date" command, what other shell tools could do it?

First I started to read: https://man.openbsd.org/date - but didn't find anything about converting to unix timestamp. Then I tried to google for many examples, but didn't helped.

Comment: The man page also mentions a `-j` flag. That seems like it could be useful. But it seems like the input format must be `YYmmddHHMMSS` (unlike FreeBSD, there is no `-f` flag)

Answer (score 3):

[The OpenBSD `date` utility](http://man.openbsd.org/date) is used to

1. set the date and/or time on the system, or
2. display the current date and/or time, or
3. parse the time and date on the format `[[[[[[cc]yy]mm]dd]HH]MM[.SS]]` without setting the system's time, using the `-j` option.

It is not date conversion tool that is as flexible as GNU `date` in its parsing capabilities.  If you want GNU `date` time/date parsing capabilities, install the `coreutils` port/package and use `gdate` instead.

Also note that the `-d` option for OpenBSD's `date` is used to set the system's value for daylight saving.

Comment: Although that tool comes with its own problems.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422978/5132